# return data after a service call

Tags: angularjs, service

I have a function which makes a service call. I have the code like below. But from success function i am unable to return the data back to calling function. How do i do this?

```
 $scope.getData = function()
      {
        var successFunc = function(serverResponse) 
        {
          if(serverResponse.header.status === "success" )
          {
            return serverResponse.data;
          }
          else
          {
           errorFunc("Error occured:");     
          }
        }
        var errorFunc = function(jsonResponse) 
        {
          console.log( "Error occured:" + JSON.stringify(jsonResponse));
        };      

        utils.svcall('abc/new', successFunc, errorFunc);    
      };

    var data     = $scope.getData();
```

Comment: utils.svcall is used for call other services which is call server url and get response?

Comment: @Paresh Gami  - It just makes request to server and returns response.

Comment: after calling   utils.svcall it will call successFunc and display data properly?